# Performance between SELECT MAX(col_name) and ROWNUM = 1

Tags: sql

I doubt on the speed and result of below queries. Could anyone give me the explanation on them? (These queries written for Oracle database)

Let say I have a table **table1(ID, itemID, trnx_date, balance, ...)**. I want to get the latest balance of an item.

Query 1:

**SELECT balance FROM table1 WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) from table1 WHERE itemID = *item_id*);**

Query 2:

**SELECT balance FROM table1 WHERE itemID = *item_id* AND rownum = 1 
ORDER BY ID DESC;**

where ***item_id*** is the variable.

Thus, do these two queries give the same result? And which one is faster or is there any other query that is faster than them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Rownum` in Oracle is calculated before the sort (my mistake earlier, I haven't used Oracle in a bit). So, this query is identical to the first:

```
SELECT 
    balance
FROM 
    (SELECT balance FROM table1 WHERE itemID = *item_id* ORDER BY ID DESC)
WHERE
    rownum = 1;
```

In this case, given an index on ID, this may be *slightly* faster.

Why haven't you just run them yourself to benchmark them?

Comment: Thanks Eric for your answer, but as I know, the process order of select statement is FROM, WHERE, ORDER BY, then SELECT. Thus, when the condition is found so it will stop finding records (because of ROWNUM=1) and then sort the result, so the result will not be the same. I have tested another table data, and the result is different !!!